# Data recovery from Public folder

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04, and I accidentally placed all my data in public folder, and restarted my laptop. Now I have lost my data, is there a way to recovery what has been lost? Thank you.

Comment: Are you in a live session? Where is the public folder located?

Comment: it is located in  files

Comment: and  what is live session?

Comment: Live session is where you put a linux dvd or usb in and booted from that. If you put data in the folder /home/<username>/Public while in a live session, it is gone.

Comment: no i did not used live session it just rebooted

Comment: please send your facebook or any other social media id where we can connect easily

Comment: i just put my data in folder /home/<username>/Public while i was using my  laptop and then it rebooted

Comment: Did you boot off of an ubuntu Dvd, or usb stick? If so, your data is gone and there is no reasonable way to recover it. If not, it depends on where that partition is mounted, the filesystem, etc.

Comment: actually i restored my p.c to factory condition and file was in folder/home/username/public so may i recover it?

Comment: Not if you restored it to factory condition. That will wipe your files unless you selected to keep all your files.

Comment: may i restore it back by any means?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can try using ddrescue and. photorec to attempt it.